# Finding an Album's Artist with the Spotify API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, spotify-app

I'm trying to use the rails gem for the [Spotify API](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify) to find the artist(s) of a particular album. I would start by retrieving the name of the album as such:

```
album_results = RSpotify::Album.search("The Eminem Show")
```

To find the artist of that album I issued the following method to the variable above:

```
album_results.artists
```

This returns a ton of data I don't need. All I want is the name of the artist. I was able to accomplish this partially by doing:

```
album_results.first.artists.first.name
=> "Eminem"
```

What I'd like it to do is **return the name all of the available artists for all album results**. I tried using the `select` method but once again got too much data for what I wanted:

```
album_results.select {|album| album.artists}
```

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) here will return all the records with `artists`.

You need to use either `collect` or `map`

```
my_artists = album_results.flat_map{ |album| 
  album.artists.collect{|artist| artist.name}
}
```

**EDIT**

Use [flat_map](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map) which returns a flattened array by default.

More efficient than using `collect` and `flatten!`

Comment: Use `flat_map` instead of the outer  `collect` followed by `flatten!`.